# Как найти файл в структуре сайта по фрагменту кода из панели разработчика

Tags: php

Добрый день! Есть сайт на CMS Bitrix, написанный на PHP. На главной странице есть всплывающее окно для заполнения параметров обратного звонка. Один из заполняемых параметров окна имеет выпадающее меню вариантов. Я администратор и у меня есть доступ к структуре сайта по FTP (Mozilla). В консоли панели разработчика Chrome я нашел ту часть кода, где нужно поменять выпадающие позиции (они перечислены в теле кода). Но я не могу найти исходный файл с этим кодом в структуре файлов. Обратиться к разработчику нет возможности. 
Поиск через меню консоли не дал результатов.
**Подскажите, где в структуре сайта стоит поискать: тип файла, возможные названия.** 
С PHP, HTML, JS знаком. Привожу фрагмент кода из консоли.[image: **введите сюда описание изображения**]

Comment: ищи по идентификатору и названию select или div, а не по значениям option. они вполне могут доставаться из бд и формироваться динамически

Comment: Результаты этой формы потом куда попадают?

Comment: Результаты этой формы добавляются в письмо-уведомление администратору на почту с пометкой "Категория"

Comment: значения опций забиты как постоянные

Comment: этой формы нет в Админка - Сервисы - Веб-формы - Настройка форм?

Comment: Вообще проблему проще было бы решить в чате. Т.к. тут дел на пару минут без всяких поисков по файлам. Если бы вы прочитали доку по битрикс, то вопроса бы даже не возникло. Тем не менее, могут быть варианты реализации и описывать каждый - слишком много букв. PS метки "Битрикс" не хватает

Answer (score 0):

если есть полный доступ, можно скачать сайт к себе и в notepad++ сделать поиск по папкам/файлам на предмет: "`</select>`"

думаю, что код захвата данных с базы находится между атрибутами `<select></select>`

Всплывающие окно может быть из js скрипта, можно поискать по вариациям `display = "none"` или `display` для поиска кода внутри js.

В любом случае нужно искать в исходном коде, а не в сгенерированном в браузере.

Comment: В ряд ли это поможет - value намекает на то, что скорее всего значения из БД.

Comment: Спасибо всем за подсказки - ответ нашел в админке Битрикса. Просто не внимательно искал. /Контент/Присланные сообщения/Темы сообщений.